# How Do I Set The Focus On Any Letter On The Android Software Keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard, softkeys

I need to set the focus over any letter of the soft-keyboard after i show it.

Actually, some devices do it by default, but some others doesn't, and i need to do it on those devices that doesn't focus a letter.

I'm using an USB Control which comes with a D-PAD (Up, Down, Left, Right, OK), and i need to use them to write, but actually i cant.

[image]

In the image, the "f" letter is focused, so i can use the control and write, that's what i need to do on the others devices.

Comment: Are you the one writing this input method editor? Or are you referring to the input method editors written by other developers?

Comment: I Just call the ShowSoftInput method, fomr the InputMethodManager class.

Comment: @IvanVerges Did you find any solution to this issue? I currently have same requirement for an app using a bluetooth remote with a d-pad.

Comment: @AustrianDude At that moment i created a custom keyboard, as i didn't find a way to do it with the native keyboard, and that was for a custom app running on Android TV Boxes, so it was not a problem for me to do it that way. I created it using some basic layouts and buttons (keys).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I suspected that this was the only way to go forward :/

Comment: I can't say it's the only way, but that's what i did at that moment.